# Unable to attach text file to Gmail in Android

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I am writing some texts to a file in cache memory. i want to sent email with that file as attachment. Tried below code but i am getting toast message says 'Unable to attach file'.

File creation and code to write data

```
        String fileName="cachelog.txt";
        File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName);
        if (!cacheFile.exists())
        {
             cacheFile.createNewFile();
        }
        }
        if(cacheFile.exists())
        {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile,true);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            buf.append(logData);
            buf.flush();
            buf.close();
        }
```

Email code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("plain/text");
            String[] to = {"testing@gmail.com"};
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, 
            context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".helper.ProviderClass", file);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            startActivity(intent)
```

Manifest file

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.medapp.helper.ProviderClass"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/cachefile" />
    </provider>




 <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
```

Comment: I think Gmail will not have access to your application's cache space. It is private to your application. Instead of this use the external storage to create this file.

Comment: `if (!cacheFile.exists())
        {
             cacheFile.createNewFile();
        }` Do not creatie already a file. It will be done by new FileOutputStream().

Comment: @Taranmeet Singh, Gmail has no idea where the file comes from as FileProvider obscures source path.

Comment: Add a fos.close();.

Comment: User File.exists() and File.canRead() and File.lenght() before you user FileProvider.

Comment: @blackapps tried to close fos. But no hope.  and  File.exists() is also true.

Comment: And the rest? Why these selective replies if you want help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create File

   ```
        String fileName="cachelog.txt";
        File file = null;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){  //Build.VERSION_CODES.R
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir()  + "/" + fileName);
        }else {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
        }

        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();


        if(file.exists())
        {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            buf.append(logData);
            buf.flush();
            buf.close();
        }
   ```
2. Send File

   ```
        String filePath = "/cachelog/cachelog.txt";
        File file = null;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){  //Build.VERSION_CODES.R
            file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir()  + "/" + filePath);
        }else {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filePath);
        }


    String mimetype = getMimeType(file.getAbsoluteFile());


        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider_paths", file);
        Intent intentaaa = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity) getActivity())
                .setStream(uri) // uri from FileProvider
                .getIntent()
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND) //Change if needed
                .setDataAndType(uri, mimetype)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        getActivity().startActivity(intentaaa);
   ```

---

```
 public static String getMimeType(File file) {
    String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());

    // Let's check the official map first. Webkit has a nice extension-to-MIME map.
    // Be sure to remove the first character from the extension, which is the "." character.
    if (extension.length() > 0) {
        //String webkitMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1));
        String webkitMimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        if (webkitMimeType != null)
            return webkitMimeType;
    }
    return "*/*";
}
```

3. create provider_paths.xml

```
<files-path
    name="share"
    path="external_files" />
<external-path
    path="Android/data/"
    name="files_root" />

<external-path
    name="pictures"
    path="Pictures/" />

<external-path
    name="storage/emulated"
    path="." />

<root-path
    name="root"
    path="." />
```

4. Add provider_paths in AndroidManifest

   ```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider_paths"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
   ```